# Laravel 5.3 php artisan migrate not working

Tags: laravel

I'm new to laravel and I'm exploring how to do migrations. I created a new users table and when I run `"php artisan migrate"` it gives me `"[PDOException] SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."` . I run `"composer dump-autoload"` then did `"composer install"` but no joy. I configured my .env file like below:

---

DB_CONNECTION=mysql

DB_HOST=127.0.0.1

DB_PORT=3306

DB_DATABASE=francis

DB_USERNAME=homestead

DB_PASSWORD=secret

---

Mysql status:
[image]

Comment: Make sure that your mysql is working!

Comment: wait I'll try that.

Comment: I tried but not working

Comment: Make your mysql work, then it would work as a charm

Comment: @SaumyaRastogi, any way we can test if mysql is working or not?

Comment: Ah ok you're using homestead. When you ssh into you homestead (`vagrant ssh`) inside the project root, and try to access your database via `mysql -u homestead -p secret` (u: homestead & p: secret are defaults). What happens? I think your problem is that you're not using valid credentials to access your DB.

Answer (score 0):

I think MySql service is not active. You have to active MySQL service. Because it's unable to connect with DB. 
Or I think disable proxy at web.config file try this.

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy> 
    <proxy usesystemdefault="False"/> 
  </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Comment: I tried using `sudo service mysql restart` but no luck

Comment: First of all you must have to ensure that your DB configuration is correct and your mysql service is running. Please check MySql service is running or not.

Comment: I am using homestead and I guess when I up the homestead mysql service also starts.

Comment: Try the above changed answer.

Comment: Sorry This didn't make as an asnwer fo my question

Comment: I can see that you are using laravel homestead, note that if you are running your project locally and not in homestead VM, you must put the `DB_HOST=192.168.10.10`, it should work like that.